# GPS library for .NET compact framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, gps

I'm thinking of writing simple application for **Windows Mobile** devices, where user could simply enter destination coordinates, and the app would calculate distance and show direction to the destination.

But I haven't found any **Free**, preferably **Open Source** library with simple API to work with **GPS**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently used open source [SharpGPS](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpGPS). It's supposed to support more devices than the example in the SDK, but both solutions work on all my hardware.

[SharpGPS](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpGPS) did make it easier to access more structured information, such as satellites in view and where they are, and has a brilliant example app. But most of this will go unused in apps that need GPS info.

Answer (score 3):

There are a set of GPS classes in the [OpenNETCF serial library](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/OpenNETCFIOSerial/tabid/252/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample GPS app in the [Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A52AF2-F524-4EC5-9155-717CBE5D25ED&displaylang=en), but you'll need a [fix](http://peterfoot.net/FixingTheWindowsMobile50GPSSampleCode.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 2):

GPS.NET is now available [free on CodePlex](http://gps3.codeplex.com/).

Comment: As an employee of a company who uses GPS.NET (and did, before it went free) I recommend it. I haven't tried the open-source version, but the version we're working from is nice.