# How to work with GPS in Windows-mobile using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Exact duplicate of: [Access GPS functionality in WinMobile phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468666/access-gps-functionality-in-winmobile-phones) and [GPS library for .NET compact framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715031/gps-library-for-net-compact-framework)

hi

how i can read GPS coordinate (x,y) in Windows-mobile using C#

thank's

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468666

Answer (score 0):

This series of articles on CodeProject might help:

[Writing Your Own GPS Applications: Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications1.aspx)
[Writing Your Own GPS Applications: Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications2.aspx)
[Writing GIS and Mapping Software for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/maps_map_net_gis.aspx)

The author of the components used in these articles is available on [CodePlex](http://gps3.codeplex.com/).